# Mysql result not show inside div (only table header)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I try to show Mysql result as table inside `<div>` after click submit button, but it just only show `<table></table>`. No problem found during posting value to process page.
So far, my script is like:

```
<form id="myform">
....................
<button id="input" type="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span>Submit </span></button>
<input name="action" value="openreport" type="hidden">
</form>
<div id="show"></div>

$("#submit").click(function(){
      var params=$("#myform").serialize();
      $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"go.php",
              data:params,
              cache :false,
              async :false,
              success : function(result) {
                   $('#show').replaceWith(result);
                   }
              });
      });
```

page go.php:

```
     <?php

         //CONNECT TO DATABASE
         $dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV, _ACCID, _PWD) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
         mysql_select_db("qdbase") or die(_ERROR17.": ".mysql_error());

         switch (postVar('action')) {
                 case 'openreport':
                         openreport(postVar('model'),postVar('line'),postVar('lot_no'));
                         break;
                         }

         function openreport($model,$line,$lot_no){
                 $Model = mysql_real_escape_string($model);
                 $Line = mysql_real_escape_string($line);
                 $Lot = mysql_real_escape_string($lot_no);

                 $group=" GROUP BY DATE ";

                 $sql="SELECT Range_sampling,DATE(Inspection_datetime) AS DATE FROM
     inspection_report WHERE Model LIKE '".$Model."'"; 
                     $sql.="AND Line LIKE '".$Line."' AND Lot_no LIKE '".$Lot."'".$group;
                     $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());

                     echo "<table border='1'>


 <tr>
     <th>Firstname</th>
     <th>Lastname</th>
     </tr>";
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
     echo("<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td></tr>");
     //  echo "<tr>";
     //  echo "<td>" . $row['Range_sampling'] . "</td>";
     //  echo "<td>" . $row['DATE'] . "</td>";
     //  echo "</tr>";
       }
     echo "</table>";

     mysql_close($dbc);
         }
         ?>
```

I have no idea because I'm not really understand how to show mysql result as a html table.

---

[image: only show table header]

Comment: You're mixing up server-side and client-side things...Wait, is that table being printed inside the javascript code block?? (which hasn't a "<script>" tag around, btw). Anyway, when the html is served the php has already been executed. You should put that php code in the "go.php" and have it response back the table

Comment: @DamienPirsy: no,actually that is in different page.

Comment: How do I tell from the code you posted? I see php code right inside the click() method. Separate the code blocks if they are on different pages, otherwise it'll be difficult to understand what you're doing..

Comment: _async_ should be true, which it is by default.

Comment: @DamienPirsy: i'm just cut the used part of my script and actually i'm using `<script>` and `<?php` also.

Comment: As soon as your PHP script echo's something, the AJAX request ends and considers that to be the result. Thus, you cannot have multiple echo statements. Use string concat and echo when you're done building the string.

Comment: Make sure form has an id="myform", the div has id="show", and submit has id="submit". @xbonez: that's incorrect. The ajax request doesn't end until the PHP script ends.

Comment: @Herbert: Really? Wow...Let me test it out.

Comment: @Herbert: yeah, you're right. It does wait until the end of the script.

Comment: @nunu: I don't think you're showing all your php code. Yun's suggestion will indeed preserve the container div, but it doesn't explain why only `<table></table>` is shown. Even if the database returned no results, the table should still contain the caption and headings. My best guess is that part of the code isn't being executed for some reason. Is there maybe an `if` statement prior to the section of code you're showing?

Comment: @Herbert: i hope that my edited post can make you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX call is made only if a button is clicked that has an id of “submit”; however, your submit button has an id of “input”. Try changing the line that reads:

`$("#submit").click(function(){`

to

`$("#input").click(function(){`

As [Yun suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766250/911182), to keep `<div id="show">...</div>` wrapped around the table, change

`$('#show').replaceWith(result);`

with

`$('#show').html(result);`

I don’t know if this will help or not, but it’s the only thing that stands out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#show').html(result);
```

instead of replaceWith to preserve the div

Answer (score 0):

you can simply load the results of your php page into div

```
    $('div#show').load('go.php',params,function() {alert('Loaded!'); });
```

Just make sure that you replace POST with REQUEST in your php file.
The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Comment: And, you can be more specific with the url if you only want to load the table i.e go.php#tableID